# How to select the Highest Value of a specific date

Tags: mysql, datetime, select

How can I select the highest value of a specific date?

My data looks like:

```
id,value_id,sensor_id,value,time(datetime)     
 1,123,gas,10,2018-01-14 01:00:00
 1,123,gas,20,2018-01-14 02:00:00
```

I tried very view things (also with MAX) like:

```
SELECT value
FROM table
WHERE sensor_id = "123"
AND value_id = "gas"
AND time = "2018-01-14"
order by time;
limit 1;
```

I need to select the highest value of specific data which was logged on a certain date (not Interval i.e. 2017-01-01 -> 2017-01-03, only for that specified date: 2018-01-14).

But I'm getting errors or the wrong values.

Comment: Note that you should use single quotes. `SELECT MAX(value) FROM table WHERE time = '2018-01-14';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT value 
FROM table
WHERE sensor_id = '123'
AND value_id = 'gas'
AND time >= '2018-01-14'
AND time < '2018-01-15'
ORDER BY value DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Use single quotes instead of the double quotes.

When you want to get the highest value you should order the column descending (**DESC**). And if it's *highest value* don't order by *time* and you could just `select max(value)` in this case as it's the returned field and then you need no order by and no limit.

The time thing I prefer doing this replacement because other way it would not work with timestamps and this way it will always work, no matter if the column is of type date or timestamp.

Comment: damn. so simple maybe it was to late yesterday :-)

Answer (score 0):

This calls for some nested queries.

First, you want to know the latest `time` for each sensor on each date.

You get that like this

```
                     SELECT DATE(time) date, sensor_id, value_id, 
                            MAX(time) lasttime
                       FROM table
                      GROUP BY DATE(time), sensor_id, value_id
```

Then you want to retrieve the `value` column for those rows. That looks like this

```
     SELECT a.value, b.date, b.lasttime, b.sensor_id, b.value_id
       FROM table a
       JOIN (
                     SELECT DATE(time) date, sensor_id, value_id, 
                            MAX(time) lasttime
                       FROM table
                      GROUP BY DATE(time), sensor_id, value_id
            ) b ON a.time=b.lasttime 
               AND a.sensor_id = b.sensor_id
               AND a.value_id = b.value_id
```

A couple of tricks make this possible. One is the use of MAX(date) ... GROUP BY DATE(date) to find the latest time within each day. The other is the join back to the original table to retrieve the `value` column,